# How can I change the placeholder text supplied in the endfloat package?

Tags: floats, endfloat

The default text for the placeholders for figures moved to the end by the `endfloat` package is "[Table XX about here]".  Because we don't spend enough time on pointless formatting issues, the publishers want a different text "(@@Insert Table X here)". From the documentation it appears that I should be able to do this using `\renewcommand` but - probably because I am failing to see something very simple - I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefne `\figureplace` (for figures), `\tableplace` (for tables) or `\floatplace` (foll all floats) to change the text and formatting of the marker text (see Section **4 Modifying marker text** of the package documentation). A little complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\renewcommand\figureplace{%
  \begin{center}
  (Insert \figurename~\thepostfigure\ here.)
  \end{center}
}
\renewcommand\tableplace{%
  \begin{center}
  (Insert \tablename~\theposttable\ here.)
  \end{center}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{A test figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
B
\caption{A test table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Since the same text (except the name of the object, of course) was used above, one could simple have said:

```
\renewcommand\floatplace[1]{%
  \begin{center}
(Insert \csname #1name\endcsname~\csname thepost#1\endcsname\ here.)
  \end{center}}
```

Comment: When compiling your example one get `(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 22 was incomplete)(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 16 was incomplete)`. This is caused by using `\renewcommand\figureplace[1]{...}` instead of `\renewcommand\figureplace{...}`. (Same for `\tableplace`)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I left the argument from `\floatplace`; now it's been corrected. Thanks for noticing.